# how to make 2 div's move parallel to each other using css

Tags: css

this is the code i am using for my project but i want the squares to move down together after the first step.it should make the squares go down at the same time and end next to each other but one the squares end up going way below the first square. Any way to fix this i found an example but without any movement. http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/623ftfc2/

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation: first 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation: first 5s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes first {
  0% {
    background: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background: green;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background: blue;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
  }
}

#2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation: second 5s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation: second 5s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes second {
  0% {
    background: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    background: green;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background: blue;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div><div id="2"></div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: your second `div` is inside your first, and because of their `position` properties, they are positioned relative to one another. The simplest is probably to change that last `top: 200px` to `top: 0`, but you might want to consider having the `div`s siblings instead of parent-child

Comment: provided the wrong fiddle?

Comment: you're applying two animations to `div#2`

Answer (score 1):

Your second div is inside your first, and because of their position properties, they are positioned relative to one another. So when you animate the first div, it moves both divs, and then when you separately animate the second div, it moves it further right and further down.

The simplest is probably to change that last top: `200px` to `top: 0`, but you might want to consider having the divs siblings instead of parent-child.

Also, `id` [can't start with a digit](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/), so I've changed `"2"` to `"d2"` below.

```css
div {
 position: relative;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;
 -webkit-animation:first 5s infinite;
 -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
 animation: first 5s infinite;
 animation-direction: alternate;
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes first{
 0% {background:red; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
 50% {background:green; left: 200px; top: 0px;}
 100% {background:blue; left: 200px; top: 200px;}
}

#d2 {
 position:absolute;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;
 -webkit-animation:second 5s infinite;
 -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
 animation: second 5s infinite;
 animation-direction: alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes second{
 0% {background:red; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
 50% {background:green; left: 200px; top: 0px;}
 100%{background:blue; left: 200px; top: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div><div id="d2"></div></div>
```